# How I "make" git 1.8.2 on debian

Tags: git, build, makefile, debian

I have an problem while compiling git.

I've tried this:
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

Error ...

Then I've installed this:http://packages.debian.org/de/sid/git-buildpackage

Same error ...

```
            GEN perl/PM.stamp
            SUBDIR gitweb
            SUBDIR ../
        make[2]: `GIT-VERSION-FILE' is up to date.
            GEN git-instaweb
            SUBDIR git-gui
            SUBDIR gitk-git
            SUBDIR perl
            SUBDIR templates
        install -d -m 755 '/usr/local/bin'
        install -d -m 755 '/usr/local/libexec/git-core'
        install   git-credential-store git-daemon git-fast-import git-http-backend git-imap-send git-sh-i18n--envsubst git-shell git-show-index git-upload-pack git-remote-testsvn git-http-fetch git-http-push git-credential-cache git-credential-cache--daemon git-remote-http git-remote-https git-remote-ftp git-remote-ftps git-am git-bisect git-difftool--helper git-filter-branch git-lost-found git-merge-octopus git-merge-one-file git-merge-resolve git-mergetool git-pull git-quiltimport git-rebase git-request-pull git-stash git-submodule git-web--browse git-add--interactive git-difftool git-archimport git-cvsexportcommit git-cvsimport git-cvsserver git-relink git-send-email git-svn git-p4 git-instaweb '/usr/local/libexec/git-core'
        install -m 644  git-mergetool--lib git-parse-remote git-rebase--am git-rebase--interactive git-rebase--merge git-sh-setup git-sh-i18n '/usr/local/libexec/git-core'
        install git git-upload-pack git-receive-pack git-upload-archive git-shell git-cvsserver '/usr/local/bin'
        make -C templates DESTDIR='' install
        make[1]: Entering directory `/home/git-1.8.5/templates'
        install -d -m 755 '/usr/local/share/git-core/templates'
        (cd blt && tar cf - .) | \
            (cd '/usr/local/share/git-core/templates' && umask 022 && tar xof -)
        make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/git-1.8.5/templates'
        install -d -m 755 '/usr/local/libexec/git-core/mergetools'
        install -m 644 mergetools/* '/usr/local/libexec/git-core/mergetools'
        install -d -m 755 '/usr/local/share/locale'
        (cd po/build/locale && tar cf - .) | \
            (cd '/usr/local/share/locale' && umask 022 && tar xof -)
        make -C perl prefix='/usr/local' DESTDIR='' install
        make[1]: Entering directory `/home/git-1.8.5/perl'
        make[2]: Entering directory `/home/git-1.8.5/perl'
        Appending installation info to /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/perllocal.pod
        make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/git-1.8.5/perl'
        make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/git-1.8.5/perl'
        make -C gitweb install
        make[1]: Entering directory `/home/git-1.8.5/gitweb'
        make[2]: Entering directory `/home/git-1.8.5'
        make[2]: `GIT-VERSION-FILE' is up to date.
        make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/git-1.8.5'
        install -d -m 755 '/usr/local/share/gitweb'
        install -m 755 gitweb.cgi '/usr/local/share/gitweb'
        install -d -m 755 '/usr/local/share/gitweb/static'
        install -m 644 static/gitweb.js static/gitweb.css static/git-logo.png static/git-favicon.png '/usr/local/share/gitweb/static'
        make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/git-1.8.5/gitweb'
        make -C gitk-git install
        make[1]: Entering directory `/home/git-1.8.5/gitk-git'
        install -m 755 gitk-wish '/usr/local/bin'/gitk
        install -d -m 755 '/usr/local/share/gitk/lib/msgs'
        install -m 644 po/de.msg '/usr/local/share/gitk/lib/msgs' &&  install -m 644 po/es.msg '/usr/local/share/gitk/lib/msgs' &&  install -m 644 po/fr.msg '/usr/local/share/gitk/lib/msgs' &&  install -m 644 po/hu.msg '/usr/local/share/gitk/lib/msgs' &&  install -m 644 po/it.msg '/usr/local/share/gitk/lib/msgs' &&  install -m 644 po/ja.msg '/usr/local/share/gitk/lib/msgs' &&  install -m 644 po/pt_br.msg '/usr/local/share/gitk/lib/msgs' &&  install -m 644 po/ru.msg '/usr/local/share/gitk/lib/msgs' &&  install -m 644 po/sv.msg '/usr/local/share/gitk/lib/msgs' && true
        make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/git-1.8.5/gitk-git'
        make -C git-gui gitexecdir='/usr/local/libexec/git-core' install
        make[1]: Entering directory `/home/git-1.8.5/git-gui'
          DEST /usr/local/libexec/git-core
            INSTALL 755 git-gui
            INSTALL 755 git-gui--askpass
            LINK        git-citool -> git-gui
          DEST /usr/local/share/git-gui/lib
            INSTALL 644 tclIndex
            INSTALL 644 about.tcl
            INSTALL 644 blame.tcl
            INSTALL 644 branch_checkout.tcl
            INSTALL 644 branch_create.tcl
            INSTALL 644 branch_delete.tcl
            INSTALL 644 branch_rename.tcl
            INSTALL 644 branch.tcl
            INSTALL 644 browser.tcl
            INSTALL 644 checkout_op.tcl
            INSTALL 644 choose_font.tcl
            INSTALL 644 choose_repository.tcl
            INSTALL 644 choose_rev.tcl
            INSTALL 644 class.tcl
            INSTALL 644 commit.tcl
            INSTALL 644 console.tcl
            INSTALL 644 database.tcl
            INSTALL 644 date.tcl
            INSTALL 644 diff.tcl
            INSTALL 644 encoding.tcl
            INSTALL 644 error.tcl
            INSTALL 644 index.tcl
            INSTALL 644 line.tcl
            INSTALL 644 logo.tcl
            INSTALL 644 merge.tcl
            INSTALL 644 mergetool.tcl
            INSTALL 644 option.tcl
            INSTALL 644 remote_add.tcl
            INSTALL 644 remote_branch_delete.tcl
            INSTALL 644 remote.tcl
            INSTALL 644 search.tcl
            INSTALL 644 shortcut.tcl
            INSTALL 644 spellcheck.tcl
            INSTALL 644 sshkey.tcl
            INSTALL 644 status_bar.tcl
            INSTALL 644 themed.tcl
            INSTALL 644 tools_dlg.tcl
            INSTALL 644 tools.tcl
            INSTALL 644 transport.tcl
            INSTALL 644 win32.tcl
            INSTALL 644 git-gui.ico
            INSTALL 644 win32_shortcut.js
          DEST /usr/local/share/git-gui/lib/msgs
            INSTALL 644 de.msg
            INSTALL 644 el.msg
            INSTALL 644 fr.msg
            INSTALL 644 hu.msg
            INSTALL 644 it.msg
            INSTALL 644 ja.msg
            INSTALL 644 nb.msg
            INSTALL 644 pt_br.msg
            INSTALL 644 ru.msg
            INSTALL 644 sv.msg
            INSTALL 644 zh_cn.msg
        make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/git-1.8.5/git-gui'
        bindir=$(cd '/usr/local/bin' && pwd) && \
            execdir=$(cd '/usr/local/libexec/git-core' && pwd) && \
            { test "$bindir/" = "$execdir/" || \
              for p in git git-shell git-upload-pack git-cvsserver; do \
                rm -f "$execdir/$p" && \
                test -z "" && \
                ln "$bindir/$p" "$execdir/$p" 2>/dev/null || \
                cp "$bindir/$p" "$execdir/$p" || exit; \
              done; \
            } && \
            for p in git-receive-pack git-upload-archive; do \
                rm -f "$bindir/$p" && \
                test -z "" && \
                ln "$bindir/git" "$bindir/$p" 2>/dev/null || \
                ln -s "git" "$bindir/$p" 2>/dev/null || \
                cp "$bindir/git" "$bindir/$p" || exit; \
            done && \
            for p in  git-add git-annotate git-apply git-archive git-bisect--helper git-blame git-branch git-bundle git-cat-file git-check-attr git-check-ignore git-check-mailmap git-check-ref-format git-checkout-index git-checkout git-clean git-clone git-column git-commit-tree git-commit git-config git-count-objects git-credential git-describe git-diff-files git-diff-index git-diff-tree git-diff git-fast-export git-fetch-pack git-fetch git-fmt-merge-msg git-for-each-ref git-fsck git-gc git-grep git-hash-object git-help git-index-pack git-init-db git-log git-ls-files git-ls-remote git-ls-tree git-mailinfo git-mailsplit git-merge git-merge-base git-merge-file git-merge-index git-merge-ours git-merge-recursive git-merge-tree git-mktag git-mktree git-mv git-name-rev git-notes git-pack-objects git-pack-redundant git-pack-refs git-patch-id git-prune-packed git-prune git-push git-read-tree git-receive-pack git-reflog git-remote git-remote-ext git-remote-fd git-repack git-replace git-rerere git-reset git-rev-list git-rev-parse git-revert git-rm git-send-pack git-shortlog git-show-branch git-show-ref git-stripspace git-symbolic-ref git-tag git-tar-tree git-unpack-file git-unpack-objects git-update-index git-update-ref git-update-server-info git-upload-archive git-var git-verify-pack git-verify-tag git-write-tree git-cherry git-cherry-pick git-format-patch git-fsck-objects git-get-tar-commit-id git-init git-merge-subtree git-peek-remote git-repo-config git-show git-stage git-status git-whatchanged; do \
                rm -f "$execdir/$p" && \
                test -z "" && \
                ln "$execdir/git" "$execdir/$p" 2>/dev/null || \
                ln -s "git" "$execdir/$p" 2>/dev/null || \
                cp "$execdir/git" "$execdir/$p" || exit; \
            done && \
            remote_curl_aliases="git-remote-https git-remote-ftp git-remote-ftps" && \
            for p in $remote_curl_aliases; do \
                rm -f "$execdir/$p" && \
                test -z "" && \
                ln "$execdir/git-remote-http" "$execdir/$p" 2>/dev/null || \
                ln -s "git-remote-http" "$execdir/$p" 2>/dev/null || \
                cp "$execdir/git-remote-http" "$execdir/$p" || exit; \
            done && \
            ./check_bindir "z$bindir" "z$execdir" "$bindir/git-add"
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I doesn't get a real error - just that stuff I already posted. I do "sudo make prefix=/usr/local install" and the install / build stops ...

Comment: You could try a `sudo strace make prefix=/usr/local install`, and see where it freezes.

Comment: I think it works fine ... close(1) = 0 munmap(0x7f713cb23000, 4096) = 0  exit_group(0) = ?

Comment: So... does `git --version` works after that?

Comment: Maybe you could install that old git before launching the compilation /installation of git. You don't need git to get the sources of git and compile/install it.

Comment: sure - so I have to uninstall the old version?!

Comment: I would remove it to avoid any side effect with the compilation.

Comment: Have you tried running the command with the fully-qualified path, like `/usr/local/bin/git --version`?  I think you're just still running the old version.  If you didn't get any error messages from the install, then it worked.

Comment: ok I think you're right - the version is the right one. So it should load it - I think.

Comment: @MadScientist - you was right ... thank you -  that was a stupid mistake

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear about what might have happened and why you might have been confused.

Suppose you had your `PATH` set so that `/usr/local/bin` comes before `/usr/bin`.  You run `git --version` and get the version from `/usr/bin/git`.

Then you build a newer Git and install it into `/usr/local/bin`.  You run `git --version` again, expecting that this time when the shell searches your `PATH` it will find `/usr/local/bin/git` first and run that.

But it probably won't, because for performance most shells, including `bash`, have a *command cache* that they use to avoid having to re-search your `PATH` every time you type a command.  Once the command is in the cache, then the shell doesn't search for it again the next time.  It just uses the same command it found last time.

To fix this you can either run `hash -r` to tell the shell to forget its internal cache, or you can exit your shell and start a new one (the cache is in memory only: it doesn't persist across/between invocations of the shell).

Answer (score 1):

It was just a fail with the git --version update, so it displayed the old - but it was already the current version.